# How to create Horizontally Scrolling Buttons With Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, emoji

Using Swift 3

Hi there I have created a collection view with 7 sections and horizontal scroll. I now want to place 7 buttons beneath the collection view so that when user swipes sideways through the collection view sections the buttons highlight AND/OR when user taps buttons the collection view scrolls to the appropriate section.

I am looking for the exact same functionality as the emoji keyboard in native apple iPhone keyboards. Users can swipe sideways to scroll through emojis and also can tap buttons under emojis to go to a certain emoji section in the emoji keyboard.

Many thanks

Comment: [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried so far? SO is more for specific code level questions and this seems like you're more wanting a tutorial.

Comment: One way to do that is to track the movement of the collection view. UICollectionView extends UIScrollView and you can either set a delegate or use KVO to observer the contentOffset property. You would still need to figure which section is being displayed so, perhaps, there is a better way.